# Why is the space complexity of Iterative Deepening Search O(bm)?

Tags: algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence

In the [Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_Intelligence%3A_A_Modern_Approach) textbook, IDS is stated to have a space complexity of `O(bm)`, where `b` = branching factor and `m` = maximum depth of tree. What nodes does IDS store during its traversal that causes it to have a `O(bm)` space complexity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) it says the space complexity is simply the depth *d* of the goal, as it is essentially a depth-first search; that is what it actually says in my copy of AIAMA (p. 88)

I can only imagine that the *O(bm)* assumes that the top level of all visited nodes is stored, which would be the branching level times the current depth. There is no need to store the higher-level nodes, as they have already been searched.

Comment: wouldn't storing the nodes be O(b^m) space ? since at each level u have 1 + b + b^2 + .. + b^(m-1) ?

Comment: @calveeen I have actually now checked my copy, and on p.88 it says the memory requirement is like depth search, O(d).

Comment: @calveeen Also, it wouldn't need to store *all* nodes, just the last level visited, as all previous layers have already been fully searched.

Comment: The standard assumption is that the branching factor `b` is a constant. We assume that all children are generated at each depth of the tree, and thus they are stored (recursively on the stack) during the DFS.